# How can I run a ruby script as root every 10 seconds on a Mac?

Tags: macos, launchd

I have the following in my /Library/LaunchDemons as com.me.filechecker.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>File Checker</string>
        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>Program</key>
        <string>/usr/bin/ruby "/Users/me/projects/filechecker/filechecker.rb"</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

I also ran

```
sudo chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.me.filechecker.plist
```

and

```
sudo chmod a+x /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.me.filechecker.plist
```

and

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.me.filechecker.plist
```

It doesn't appear to be running (or if it is running, it isn't doing anything). How can I debug this and get it to work?

Comment: What are the `permissions` you've got set for the script, and have you also tried running it as a `cronjob` perhaps? One more thought — consider posting the `ruby script` also; it might be an issue in the script.

Comment: Do cronjobs run as root? If yes, what do I do to add it as a cronjob and will it start automatically every time I start up my computer? The permissions are a+x chmodded.

Comment: The file has permissions... -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  458 May 10 11:36 com.me.filechecker.plist   (IDK what "wheel" is)

Comment: Those permissions should generally be fine for `cronjobs` or `daemons`. `cronjobs` can use permissions according to whatever user needs to run the task, it would run automatically when you start you computer as well, so it's fairly flexible. Does your script run normally when you execute it from `Terminal.app`, and what does it do? As I mentioned before you might consider posting the script so we can see what it's doing exactly. Also try this command in Terminal: `ps aux | grep filechecker` - do you see anything listed?

Comment: `wheel` is the name of the special user group that the `root` user belongs to - see http://superuser.com/a/191969/139307.

Comment: I haven't checked yet. Give me some time.

Answer (score 2):

The executable name and its arguments should be passed the same way as to [`execvp`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/execvp.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/execvp) function. You have to pass executable name and all arguments separately. Arguments should be passed in `ProgramArguments` key:

```
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/usr/bin/ruby</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
       <string>/usr/bin/ruby</string>
       <string>/Users/me/projects/filechecker/filechecker.rb</string>
    </array>
```

You can also skip `Program` key in this case. More in [`man launchd.plist`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.plist.5.html)

```
 Program <string>
 This key maps to the first argument of execvp(3).  If this key is missing, then the first element of
 the array of strings provided to the ProgramArguments will be used instead.  This key is required in
 the absence of the ProgramArguments key.

 ProgramArguments <array of strings>
 This key maps to the second argument of execvp(3).  This key is required in the absence of the Program
 key. Please note: many people are confused by this key. Please read execvp(3) very carefully!
```

Comment: Good advice, but you shouldn't double-quote the value of the second `<string>` element - no shell is involved, so no quote removal is performed. With the quotes in place, they become part of the _argument itself_.

Comment: P.S.: I'd say that for simplicity it's generally better to only ever use the `ProgramArguments` key.

Answer (score 2):

To complement [baf's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30156011/45375)  (which shows how to use the `ProgramArguments` key to invoke an executable with arguments correctly):

While making the `*.plist` file executable should do no harm, there is no need to do so.
What matters is that the file:

1. *must be* owned by the user in whose context the job runs (which you've done with `sudo chown root`, though `sudo chown root:wheel` is better for consistency).
2. *must not be* group- or world-writeable for security reasons; thus, a typical file in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`, whose `*.plist` files run as the `root` user (by default), reports the following at the beginning of an output line from `ls -l`: `-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel ...`

`launchctl load`, unfortunately, only generates an error message if the `*.plist` file is *syntactically* invalid, and generally *always* sets exit code `0`, even in the event of an error.

To **troubleshoot**, **open `Console.app`** and look for `com.apple.xpc.launchd` entries:

If I do this after loading your `*.plist` file, I see several relevant entries, notably this one:

```
5/10/15 11:33:38.653 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (File Checker[61800]) 
Could not find and/or execute program specified by service: 2: 
No such file or directory: /usr/bin/ruby "/Users/me/projects/filechecker/filechecker.rb"
```

This tells us that `launchd` thinks that the *executable* path is the *whole string* `/usr/bin/ruby "/Users/me/projects/filechecker/filechecker.rb"`, because the `Program` key must *only* contain the executable path.

With the correction suggested by [baf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30156011/45375), `launchd` should invoke the command correctly.